# JMH framework to measure performance of Jave EE application with near-to-real DB

Tags: java, performance, performance-testing, jmh

I'm working on performance framework. It is internal project of our company, developed to measure performance of applications(POS and related stuff). Work of current version is based on synthetic transactions, which play role of stopwatch. It works in one thread and interacts with real DB with previously generated data(to fill DB we use own DSL language, so data inside is near-to-real). Our next step - implementing ability to measure performance in multiple threads. Was decided using JMH like a base. But we encountered several problem:

1. A lot of our methods needs instances of classes as parameters. I can't find  examples or references, how it can be reached(params are always primitives or wrapers).

   - **question:** Is it possible to get object-parameters from DB  and use  them for invoking methods without side effects? "From DB" because I must be sure that for these parameters method will execut real work.
2. After measuring performance of delete or save methods, we need to restore previous state of DB. Previously, we used transaction rollback.

   - **question:**
     Is it possible somehow implement transaction rollback for methods generated by JMH? Is it possible to wrap JMH method into transaction?

I'm sorry for so large question. Thank you in advance.